# Symfony validation - set the property path in custom validation act

Tags: symfony, validation, constraints

I would like to ask, how to set the property path on the constraint violation.

So far, i'm doing a normal validation like (where user is a normal Entity with some predefined constraints - which are working as aspected):

```
$validationErrors = $this->validator->validate($user);
```

Next, in the user registration controller method, i'm trying to do a manual approach (because putting the constraint directly inside the user entity would cause validation on the password each time)

I'm validating the password when needed like this:

```
$passwordLength = mb_strlen($password);
$passwordMinLength = new Assert\Length(null, 8);
$passwordErrors = $this->validator->validate($passwordLength, [ $passwordMinLength ]);
```

And after that, i'm adding the result to the existing collection:

```
$validationErrors->addAll($passwordErrors);
```

But when i inspect the violation generated by the password, theres no propertyPath defined on it. I build a custom twig extension, which relies on the propertypath being set. How can i tell it to use the propertyPath called 'password' on the `$passwordErrors` array?

I hope you can understand my question :).

Best regards!

Rob

**EDIT:**
I found the for me working workaround solution. I'm sure, that this is not the optimal way for solving my problem, but as i already wasted a few hours for this little thing, i decided to rather pick the workaround instead of working more hours on this little thing.

**My workaround solution**
As i wanted to set the propertyPath for each violation though i couldn't access the private property **propertyPath**, i solved it in the following way:

At first i created a closure function:

```
$closure = Closure::bind(function (ConstraintViolation $violation) {
    $violation->propertyPath = 'password';
}, null, ConstraintViolation::class);
```

And then i called it for each violation:

```
foreach ($passwordErrors as $violation) {
    // $violation->propertyPath = 'password';
    $closure($violation);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you need a Class Constraint Validator.
You need to add this to the Constraint class:

```
public function getTargets()
{
    return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
}
```

And with this, the validator’s `validate()` method gets an object as its first argument and the `atPath()` method is used to define the property which the validation error is associated to.

```
class ProtocolClassValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($protocol, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if ($protocol->getFoo() != $protocol->getBar()) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->atPath('foo')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how to modify existing violations
Instead of using

```php
$validationErrors->addAll($passwordErrors);
```

In your custom Validator, use this

```php
/** @var ConstraintViolationInterface $violation */
foreach ($validationErrors as $violation) {
    $this->context->buildViolation($violation->getMessage())
        ->atPath('password')
        ->addViolation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I use standard constraints then I use this approach:

```
public function setViolationsPath(
    ConstraintViolationListInterface $violations,
    string $pathName
): void {
    $path = new ReflectionProperty(ConstraintViolation::class, 'propertyPath');
    $path->setAccessible(true);

    foreach ($violations as $violation) {
        $path->setValue($violation, $pathName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use new validator context. Also, this approach allow to make many validations in one context and get all results by `$contextualValidator->getViolations()`.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationListInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class SomeService
{
    public function __construct(private ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
    }

    public function validate(string $password): ConstraintViolationListInterface
    {
        $passwordLength = mb_strlen($password);
        $passwordMinLength = new Assert\Length(null, 8);

        $contextualValidator = $this->validator->startContext();
        $contextualValidator->atPath('password')->validate($passwordLength, [ $passwordMinLength ]);

        $passwordErrors = $contextualValidator->getViolations();

        return $passwordErrors;
    }
}
```